# Number of Record Limit in the DE when using desicion split (mc)

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-designer

I am using data extension name A as an entry source
and in the journey, using decision split, I want to compare the data with an data extension name B.
In this case, B is connected with data designer.

If there are more than 30M records in data extension B, can it work?
I am worried that it might be hard to compare the data with huge records.

Thank you.

Comment: 30 million sounds like a lot. Do you have multiple records per contact in this DE? If so, you should be careful with decision splits: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237250/use-cases-for-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-in-contact-builder/237326